# notification does not appear?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Here is my **notification builder** func:

```
public class NotificationHelper {

final static String CHANNEL_ID = "MY_CHANNEL_ID";
final static String CHANNEL_NAME = "MY_CHANNEL_NAME";


public static Notification buildNotificationInstance(Context ctx, String title, String message) {

    Notification notification;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, CHANNEL_ID);
    } else {
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    }

    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(bm);


    notification = mBuilder.build();


    return notification;
    }
}
```

And I **try to show the notification** on Activity's onCreate():

```
Notification notification = NotificationHelper.buildNotificationInstance(this, "title", "message");
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

The notification doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

I test on **Android 8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the notification channel for it to work:
Try this:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationChannel.setDescription("description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
```

Comment: Android SDK consistent and clear, as always. Tanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

you must add pendingIntent for notificationBuilder as well , like this :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

mBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: why ?? you need to add intent as well to make the app navigate to activity you want when click the navigation

Comment: Wrong. Notifications not everytime used to open activities. Also, it is just not work :)

Comment: ya i know , I meant if you want to navigate to another activity

Comment: try empulater or phone less than 8 , i think in phone 8 maybe you need to add something different, just to check the problem from the code or from the android version